# Best UAE for OSX?

Tags: macos, amiga

What is the best UAE version for OSX?

I have tried E-UAE and there was something weird going on with the emulated screen. It didn't seem solid at all.  I tried PUAE too, and it seemed much better, but in fullscreen the screen gets a very yellow tint, and as a a window, the mouse cursor gets trailed by the OSX cursor, and sometimes they get so far away from each other, that things in the Amiga window can not be clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FS-UAE (http://fs-uae.net/) works great. With this emulator, I don't experience any of the display or mouse problems you're mentioning.

Comment: If you are offering a product recommendation, explain why it is the perfect item the OP needs, and potentially any costs, or screenshots. This answer is consider very low in quality as is; I would recommend [edit]ing it to improve it. Thanks